# iOS text scroll to top inside a TextView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uitextview

This is my first iOS project.

I created a `textview` from the storyboard.

What I want to achieve is, if I reach the 7th line end, the 7th line should scroll to top i.e. it should now be at line 1 and the next lines should append. This is a speech recognition app and the words would be shown in real-time.

I have tried my best to demonstrate how I want the text to scroll:

[image]

I tried following options:

Option 1:

```
  self.textView.scrollToView(self.commentsHeader, animated: true)
```

Option 2:

```
  self.setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: false)
```

I also tried to implement the same using UITableView, but the only thing I'm able to do, is to scroll the entire view to top, I want the previous text to disappear and only the last line to be shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should look for is the method `setContentOffset(CGPoint, animated: Bool)` from `UIScrollView` which is your option two.

The tricky part would be to calculate the exact offset needed, but you can do that either using a scaled-height (something like `0.8*textView.frame.height`) or by calculating it based on the `lineHeight` of the font you are using in the `UITextView`.

I hope this answers.

Comment: I tried using this. But it doesn't work. Thanks for the help